# Array calculating min, max, and average output: min, max, and average

Tags: vb.net

I put comments on the average output since I kept getting error messages about that. 
My out keeps saying:

> Maximum value: 33
>   Minimum value: 33

What am I doing wrong?

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Module MinMax
Sub Main()
    ' Declare a named constant for array size here
    Const MAX_NUMS As Integer = 10

    ' Declare array here
    Dim numbers() As Integer = {33, 12, -6, 1001, 57, -1, 999, 365, 921, 724}
    'Dim num1 As Integer
    'Dim num2 As Integer
    ' Use this integer variable as your loop index
    Dim loopIndex As Integer = 0

    ' Use this variable to store the number input by user
    Dim value As Integer

    ' String version of number input by user
    Dim valueString As String

    ' Use these variables to store the minimim and maximum values
    Dim min As Integer
    Dim max As Integer

    ' Use these variables to store the total and the average
    Dim total As Double
    Dim average As Double

    ' Write a loop to get values from user and assign to array
    For loopIndex = 0 To MAX_NUMS - 1
        valueString = InputBox$("Enter a value: ")
        value = Convert.ToInt32(valueString)
        ' Assign value to array
        'num1 = loopIndex + 1
        'num2 = loopIndex - 1
    Next loopIndex
    ' Assign the first element in the array to be the minimum and the maximum
    min = numbers(0)
    max = numbers(0)
    ' Start out your total with the value of the first element in the array
    total = numbers(0)
    ' Write a loop here to access array values starting with numbers(1)
    'For loopIndex = 0 To MAX_NUMS - 1
    '    loopIndex(0) + MAX_NUMS = max
    '    loopIndex(0) - MAX_NUMS = min
    ' Next loopIndex
    ' Within the loop test for minimum and maximum values

    ' Also accumulate a total of all values


    ' Calculate the average of the 10 values
    average = loopIndex / MAX_NUMS

    ' Print the values stored in the numbers array

    ' Print the maximum value, minimum value, and average
    System.Console.WriteLine("Maximum value: " & max)
    System.Console.WriteLine("Minimum value: " & min)
    ' System.Comsole.WriteLine("Average = " & average)
End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Probably because `min = numbers(0)` and `max = numbers(0)` both point to the first item in your array which is 33... Unless you think comments will actually do what they say.

Comment: You assign `min` to `numbers(0)` and `max` to `numbers(0)`. That means you assign min and max to the first number of your array. Are you really surprised by the result you're getting?

Comment: I imagine average also always comes out to 0.9 as well.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the code that doesn't affect the output, you're left with this:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Module MinMax
    Sub Main()
        Dim numbers() As Integer = {33, 12, -6, 1001, 57, -1, 999, 365, 921, 724}

        Dim min As Integer
        Dim max As Integer

        min = numbers(0)
        max = numbers(0)

        System.Console.WriteLine("Maximum value: " & max)
        System.Console.WriteLine("Minimum value: " & min)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Basically, you're:

1. Declaring an array of integers.
2. Declaring two default integers.
3. Assigning the value of the two default integers both to the first integer of the array (33).
4. Writing the two integers to the console.

In all of your other code, at no point do you modify the array or the two integers you're outputting.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is strange.  You have a constant-initialized array, yet you seem to want the user to input the array values, If that's the case, you should modify the first loop like this

```
    For loopIndex = 0 To MAX_NUMS - 1
        valueString = InputBox$("Enter a value: ")
        value = Convert.ToInt32(valueString)
        ' Assign value to array
        numbers(loopIndex) = value
    Next loopIndex
```

Next you want to get min, max and avg number, this part of your code is fine:

```
min = numbers(0)
max = numbers(0)
' Start out your total with the value of the first element in the array
total = numbers(0)
```

Then you have commented the loop that should do the actual work. You could write it like this

```
 ' We start loop with index 1 since index 0 is already accounted for 

   For loopIndex = 1 To MAX_NUMS - 1  
      If numbers(loopIndex) < min Then min = numbers(loopIndex)
      If numbers(loopIndex) > max Then max = numbers(loopIndex)
      ' accrue total value
      total = total + numbers(loopIndex)
   Next loopIndex



   ' After the loop ends, the minimum value and the maximum value will be correctly
   ' placed in min and max respectively

   ' Now compute average
   average = total / MAX_NUMs
```

Hope this is clear enough.  Good Luck!